# Database design query

Tags: database, database-design

I'm trying to work out a sensible approach for designing a database where I need to store a wide range of continuously changing information about pets. The categories of data can be broken down into, for example, behaviour, illness etc. Data will be submitted on a regular basis relating to these categories, so i need to find a good way to design the db to efficiently accommodate this. A simple approach would just to store multiple records for each pet within each relevant table - e.g the behaviour table would store the behaviour data and would simply have a timestamp for each record along with the identifier for that pet. When querying the db, it would be straightforward to query the one table with the pet id, using the timestamps to output the correct history of submissions. Is there a more sensible way around this or does that make sense?

Comment: Wait, you've forgotten something..

Comment: You will probably start receiving more help if you take the time to accept best answers.  Not doing so is a discouragement for a lot of people.

Comment: Believe it or not I actually didn't know about doing that - apologies, I now have an OpenID account so i'll go through my previous posts and fix them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a combination of lookup tables with a strong use of foreign keys.  I think what you are suggesting is very common.  For example, get me all the reported illnesses for a particluar pet during this data range would look something like:

```
Select *
  from table_illness
 where table_illness.pet_id = <value>
   and date between table_illness.start_date and table_illness.finish_date
```

You could do that for any of the tables.  The lookup tables will be a link between, for example, table_illness.illness_type and illness_types.illness_type.  The illness_types table is where you would store the details on the types of illnesses.

Answer (score 2):

When designing a database you should build your tables to mimic real-life objects or concepts.  So in that sense the design you suggest makes sense.  Each pet should have its own record in a pet table which doesn't change.  Changing information should then be placed into the appropriate table which has the pet's id.  The time stamp method you suggest is probably what I would do -- unless of course this is for a vet or something.  Then I'd create an appointment table with the date and connect the illness or behavior to the appointment as well.